# vertx updateresult->keys empty in postgresql insert statement

Tags: postgresql, vert.x

I am getting empty array as output of insert statement. I am using postgresql 9.5, vertx-postgresql-sql-client 3.4.2 version.

I have searched in github, googled it but didn't get anywhere.

```
id = dbconn.update( "insert into $tblname (${keys.joinToString(",")}) values (${vals.joinToString(",")}) RETURNING _id;" )
println( id?.keys )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vertx-postgresql-sql-client` is not a known vertx component, are referring to:

- vertx-jdbc-client
- vertx-mysql-postgresql-client

With jdbc the driver should handle it for you and you don't need the `RETURNING...` sql code. with the late driver, due to its internal you should use `query` instead of `update` as from the Postgres documentation, the `RETURNING...` sql code returns a result set so you can iterate it at the code level.